# Two divs (one with absolute height, the other with scrollbar)

Tags: html, css

**I want to have the following website style:**
[image]

The current styles of "OTHER DIV" AND "MOTHER DIV" are displayed in the picture. How do I have to style the other divs like `.div_top` and `.div_bottom` so that I get only in `.div_bottom` a scrollbar if it's needed?

**In addition I want that the scrollbar in `.div_bottom` adjusts itself when `.div_top` gets bigger (in height):**
[image]

I think the height of `.div_top` **has to be** `auto` because there is a div inside `.div_top` which can be hidden and shown with jQuery.

**@JonasLoerken**

[image]

This is your second result. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.Aside {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.Main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
.Main__header {
  height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.Main__content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<aside class="Aside">#Aside</aside>
<main class="Main">
  <header class="Main__header">#Header</header>
  <section class="Main__content">
    <h1 class="Main__content-header">#Scroll</h1>
    <p class="Main__content-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.other-div {
    width: 30%;
    height: 500px /* User Percent */;
    float:left;
    background: orange;
    display: block;
}

.mother-div {
    height: 500px;
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
    background: gray;
}

.top {
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.bottom {
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[Try it out!](http://jsfiddle.net/shj0ds1x/)

Comment: But I want no scrolling in `.mother-div`. I only want to scroll in `.div_bottom`

Comment: Set the "overflow: hidden;" and the in the div_bottom "overflow: scroll;".

Comment: With this solution which I tried already I have two problems: When the height of `.div_top` gets bigger, the scrollbar of `.div_bottom` doesn't adjust itself -> so if you scroll then, not all content is displayed. The second problem is that this doesn't work on mobile devices

Comment: Does this work when the height of `.top` is `auto`? Because `.top` gets bigger in height if u click a button (via jQuery). EDIT: I tested it out and when the height of `.top` is `auto` the `.bottom`-div gets over the bottom-border of the yellow div (`.other_div`)

Comment: Can you updte your fiddle please? When I try to set height of `.top` to auto it does not work propertly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shj0ds1x/2/ - But the bottom_div does not uses the full space. With this option, it does: http://jsfiddle.net/shj0ds1x/3/

Comment: I added a picture to my first post/question. How can I fix it?

Comment: This is not an issue. I positioned the top-div absolute. As a consequence the top-div is overlapping the bottom-div, because it is "not in the grid" anymore. I did that, because the height of the top-div is variable, so you cant't define the bottom-div with a fix height. Do you know what i mean? The heights of both elements are not fixed...

Comment: And how can I get it done that the bottom-div adjusts its height when the top-div got bigger/smaller in height?